# unable to query data in firebase using unity3d and c#

Tags: c#, firebase, unity-game-engine, nosql

Does anyone know how to query in firebase using unity3d on C#. I have seen some examples in java and javascript, but don't know how to do it in c#.

Answer (score 2):

You can send HTTP requests to firebase RESTful APIs, and so, you just need a simple HTTP client library in your C# code.

and also use firebase unity3d client library.

for async query example:

```
FirebaseDatabase.DefaultInstance
  .GetReference("Leaders")
  .GetValueAsync().ContinueWith(task => {
    if (task.IsFaulted) {
      // Handle the error...
    }
    else if (task.IsCompleted) {
      DataSnapshot snapshot = task.Result;
      // Do something with snapshot...
    }
  });
```

Firebase official guide here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/unity/retrieve-data

Comment: in unity3d?  do u=you have any examples i can look at?

Comment: how about your firebase query in u3d?

Comment: also, your can use firebase u3d client library. For example: `FirebaseDatabase.DefaultInstance.GetReference("url").Child("path").RemoveValueAsync();`

Comment: Query query = FirebaseDatabase.DefaultInstance.GetReference("customer"); query.OrderByChild("email").EqualTo(name.text).Reference.RemoveValueAsync;

Comment: i tried this too Query query = FirebaseDatabase.DefaultInstance.GetReference("customer").OrderByChild("email").EqualTo(name.text); query.Reference.RemoveValueAsync();  but someone is telling me to add a listener but idk how

Comment: he told me to use this as reference but im confused mdatabaseReference.child("users").orderByKey().equalTo(uid).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() { @Override public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) { for (DataSnapshot postsnapshot :dataSnapshot.getChildren()) { String key = postsnapshot.getKey(); dataSnapshot.getRef().removeValue(); }

Comment: I Tried that but that only deletes nodes by numbers not by name FirebaseDatabase.DefaultInstance.GetReference("customer").Child(stock.text).RemoveValueAsync();

Comment: i posted more information on this other question i asked https://stackoverflow.com/posts/52268105/revisions

Comment: what is that task =&gt?